# Pandas reading some xlsx files but not others

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx, xlrd

**Resolution:**

I tried with other venvs I have and the problem was in the Pandas version.

I unistalled Pandas 1.2.3 and installed 1.1.5.

I still don't know what was causing the problem, but it seemed to fix.

**My question before solving:**

I'm not sure how to solve this. I've already read a lot of posts, most of them multiple times but couldn't find anything similar.

I'm trying to make Pandas(1.2.3) read a xlsx file in Python(3.9.2).
It reads some files that are .xlsx but does not read this specific one.

The file has nothing special and earlier today I managed to make the program read it, but for some reason, now it`s returning  ****init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'**

I've already imported xlrd and pyopenxl. Added the line below:

```
xlrd.xlsx.ensure_elementtree_imported(False, None)
xlrd.xlsx.Element_has_iter = True
```

But whenever I insert the code I get an error.

Btw, engine='openpyxl' within pandas.read_excel returns the same error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f4146a2a158f> in <module>
      1 #Reading the downloaded files
----> 2 Trade = pd.read_excel(Path)
      3 # IGF = pd.read_excel(Path2)
      4 Trade

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1129         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1130 
-> 1131         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1132 
   1133     def __fspath__(self):

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    473         """
    474         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 475         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    476 
    477     @property

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    389             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    390             self.handles.handle.seek(0)
--> 391             self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    392         elif isinstance(self.handles.handle, bytes):
    393             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(self.handles.handle))

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    484         from openpyxl import load_workbook
    485 
--> 486         return load_workbook(
    487             filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    488         )

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    279         self.read_properties()
    280         self.read_theme()
--> 281         apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
    282         self.read_worksheets()
    283         self.parser.assign_names()

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in apply_stylesheet(archive, wb)
    196 
    197     node = fromstring(src)
--> 198     stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
    199 
    200     wb._borders = IndexedList(stylesheet.borders)

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101         for k in attrs:
    102             del node.attrib[k]
--> 103         return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
    104 
    105 

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):
     86                     #complex type
---> 87                     obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
     88                 else:
     89                     #primitive

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):
     86                     #complex type
---> 87                     obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
     88                 else:
     89                     #primitive

~\.virtualenvs\Info-Center-Download-ayrFyCk4\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xfid'
[7]
```

I have a Venv installed and these are the program versions I`m using

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17
backcall                  0.2.0
certifi                   2020.12.5
chardet                   4.0.0
colorama                  0.4.4
configparser              5.0.2
crayons                   0.4.0
decorator                 4.4.2
et-xmlfile                1.0.1
future                    0.18.2
idna                      2.10
ipykernel                 5.5.0
ipython                   7.21.0
ipython-genutils          0.2.0
jedi                      0.18.0
jupyter-client            6.1.12
jupyter-core              4.7.1
lml                       0.1.0
numpy                     1.20.1
openpyxl                  3.0.7
pandas                    1.2.3
parso                     0.8.1
pefile                    2019.4.18
pickleshare               0.7.5
pip                       21.0.1
prompt-toolkit            3.0.18
pyexcel                   0.6.6
pyexcel-io                0.6.4
Pygments                  2.8.1
pyinstaller               4.2
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2021.1
python-dateutil           2.8.1
pytz                      2021.1
pywin32                   300
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
pyzmq                     22.0.3
requests                  2.25.1
selenium                  3.141.0
setuptools                53.0.0
six                       1.15.0
texttable                 1.6.3
tornado                   6.1
traitlets                 5.0.5
urllib3                   1.26.4
wcwidth                   0.2.5
webdriver-manager         3.3.0
wheel                     0.36.2
xlrd                      1.2.0
XlsxWriter                1.3.7
```

Comment: This looks very much like a broken source file: element names are case sensitive in XML.

Comment: I tried other files that have upper case and space between letters (Ex: \\Downloads\\Realtime Numbers Managers Control.xlsx) and it reads.
I just can't find a logic why only these 2 specific files are not being read.